# Using loop variable outside the loop PHP

Tags: php, loops

This is probably very simple but I cannot figure it out and my searches have come up blank.

Here is what I have in mind:

```
<?php

$var1 = 0.0;
for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
    $var1 = $var1 + $i;
}
echo $var1[4]; // This would give 0, I believe.
?>
```

I hope my example made it clear what I'm trying to do, and I'm sure there is a simple solution, I just unfortunately cannot find it.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Did you test it? Your example uses an array key `[4]` on a scalar variable `$var1`. If not for that, it would work.

Comment: That's an infinite loop.

Comment: As long as the variable is defined outside of the `loop` scope, it is accessible outside of the `loop`.

Comment: Sorry; I can't figure out what that's trying to do - you set up `$var1` as an integer, but you're treating it as an array in the `echo` at the end?

Comment: @Matt in PHP, the scope isn't limited inside loops (like most other languages) - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @newfurniturey that's a good point, but it's still good practice to initialize your variables prior to using them.

Comment: thanks guys, & fixed the infinite loop :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
  $arr = array();
  for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++){
      $arr[$i - 1] = $i;
  }
  echo $arr[4]; // This would give 5.
?>
```

Comment: indeed, this is what I was going for though.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the value of $i in your loop, which would cause it to go on forever, I'm afraid.  Also, you define $var1 as a number, but then you're trying to access it as though it were an array.